# Opengl-es onTouchEvents problem or a draw problem?

Tags: android, opengl-es, user-input, touch-event, ondraw

I am just getting started with using opengl in my apps and I get it fine =) but I've hit a brick wall recently as I have been attempting to work out methods of user input.
I decided to start with a simple process that draws a square to the screen at the position you touch the screen. Unfortunatly the app doesn't seem to register the input.

Here is my code:

The app opens with this activity >>

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Practice extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView (this);
    view.setRenderer(new GLSurfaceRenderer());
    setContentView(view);    
}
}
```

This initializes a full screen SurfaceView.

Next the renderer

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.view.MotionEvent;


public class GLSurfaceRenderer implements Renderer{

private FlatColoredSquare Square;
private float setx = 0;
private float sety = 0; 


    public GLSurfaceRenderer () {   
    Square = new FlatColoredSquare();

}
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event, GL10 gl){
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){    
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(event.getX(), event.getY(), -10);
        Square.draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        }

        return true;

    }



 @Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
         gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |
            GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
         gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(setx, sety, -10);
    Square.draw(gl);        
    gl.glPopMatrix();
         }






@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

}



}
```

As you can see there is an onTouchEvent that gets the coordinates of the event and sets them to the floats at the top.  The draw method then uses these coordinates to set the position of the square.  I don't think the draw method here updates enough to redraw the square.  How can I set the draw method to update the square onTouch? As well as trying to set the square to draw from inside the onTouch method I have also left it blank like:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){    
        setx = event.getX();
        sety = event.getY();
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Both of these return the same results =(
So am I doing the onTouchEvent wrong?
or do I have to force the draw method to update somehow?
and how would I implement this properly?

Thank you for your time

EDIT:

Managed to get the code to register an onTouchEvent by moving the method over to the Practice class.

EDIT: Made some more improvements code now works properly to an extent but instead of redrawing the square in the desired place I instead get a blank cleared screen.

Here is edited Practice

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.app.ui.GLSurfaceRenderer;



public class Practice extends Activity {
private GLSurfaceRenderer glSurfaceRenderer;
public static float setx;
public static float sety;




/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView (this);
    view.setRenderer(glSurfaceRenderer = new GLSurfaceRenderer());

    setContentView(view);
}
@Override
public synchronized boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            glSurfaceRenderer.randomMethod(event);
    }

    return true;

}
}
```

And edited Renderer Class

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.view.MotionEvent;




public class GLSurfaceRenderer implements Renderer{
private float setx; 
private float sety; 

private FlatColoredSquare square;


    public GLSurfaceRenderer () {   
    square = new FlatColoredSquare();


}

    public synchronized void randomMethod(MotionEvent event){
        setx = event.getX();
        sety = event.getY();
    }



@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
         gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |
            GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
         gl.glLoadIdentity();


             gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(setx, sety, -10);
    square.draw(gl);        
    gl.glPopMatrix();

         }








@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

}



}
```

Any ideas?
Here is the square code

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class FlatColoredSquare {
private float vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};

private short indices[] = {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,};

private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;


public FlatColoredSquare() {
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length*2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
    indexBuffer.put(indices);
    indexBuffer.position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, 
                      GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here.

1) You are using your own, custom `onTouchEvent()` method. Your method `onTouchEvent()` with the arguments `MotionEvent event, GL10 gl` has no official support in the SDK.

2) You are modifying data that explicitly are running in another thread. The touch event's threads differs from the GL thread.

Your solution is simple. Override [`onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) (or set an [`onTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to your `GLSurfaceView` class) in your activity class and call a method (which should be declared as `synchronized`) in your view class within it. An alternative is to update logic in a different thread, however, that is up to you to decide.

Comment: I put my onTouchEvent in my opening activity (is that what you meant by activity class?) but I don't know how to make the setx and sety variables available to the draw method in the renderer class or indeed how to syncronise the methods. Could you elaborate on how this is done please =)

Comment: @Jack: Yes. Create a `public synchronized void randomMethod(MotionEvent event) { /* Stuff... */}` in your renderer class. That method should you call inside your activity's `onTouchEvent()` method.

Comment: and the onTouchEvent is in the opening activity ("Practice" in this case)? and If call the event.getX() and getY in the onTouchEvent what do I call in the syncronised void? Have I got the wrong end of the stick? =(

Comment: @Jack: Yes. You pass the `MotionEvent` further to your renderer class by calling the `randomMethod(MotionEvent event)` from your Practice class inside Practice's `onTouchEvent()`.

Comment: I'm sorry for being a real noob, but how do you call a foreign method across classes. It doesn't accept 'public syncronized void randomMethod();' when called inside the on touch event have I missed something like importing the class or something =(

Comment: @Jack: You should keep a global reference to your renderer class in your activity class.

Comment: Okay I've figured that out =) but now I'm getting NullPointerExceptions (which at least is a step forward because it shows that the Touch Events are registering =P)  Having googled around I haven't been able to find out exactly what could cause this exception. At the moment my ontouchevent gets x and y and then calls randomMethod which in turn calls onDrawFrame which doesn't sound right to me =/ where am I going wrong

Comment: @Jack: Post the error log in order to see where you gets NPE.

Comment: @Jack: Change `view.setRenderer(new GLSurfaceRenderer());` to `view.setRenderer(glSurfaceRenderer = new GLSurfaceRenderer());`. Also, make your name variables in a way so that the first letter is lowercase.

Comment: still seems to be having trouble with that line and now the onDrawFrame method as well (at line 43)

Comment: @Jack: Why are you calling `onDrawFrame` in your `randomMethod`? Just change your x and y variables there.

Comment: Hmm curious =/ No more crashing =D but the square doesn't redraw when setx and sety are changed it just simply disappears =(

Comment: @Jack: I have no idea, you maybe have to edit your question with your clean, actual code so we can see how much you have edited.

Comment: How does your FlatColoredSquare look like?

Comment: @Jack: Test change the fourth value of `glColor4f()` to `1.0f`. :-)

Comment: Still nothing =( is it possible that the draw method is still not being called and the surface is just getting cleared by something else

Comment: What the heck?! Have you tried a simple tutorial about this?

Comment: I've been on [jayway](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/) but that contains no user input methods and I also have this [bouncing ball tutorial](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_2D.html) which contains a bit on onTouchEvents further down but the code seems to be layed out in one class rather than two

Comment: @Jack: Now I think I got it. What happens if you instead of setX and setY passes in zeros in `glTranslatef()`? Does it show up?

Comment: Yep, the problem is that your touch in 2D screen coordinates does not apply to your 3D world space. You have to project a ray from 2D into your 3D world. Read more about it [here](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cast+raying#sclient=psy&hl=sv&source=hp&q=ray+casting+opengl&pbx=1&oq=ray+casting+opengl&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=7465l11800l1l11930l26l21l4l5l5l0l253l2433l1.8.5l15&fp=1&biw=1680&bih=949&cad=b&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.).

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why that's necsasary =( I know objects don't draw when close to the origin but I haven't got anywhere in the code that moves the square any closer along the z-axis, that position is hard coded at -10.

Comment: That's necessary because when you are touhing your screen you are doing it in 2D, not in 3D. Therefore, from a 2D perspective you need to cast a ray from your touch point in 2D to your 3D space.

Comment: You know I think It may be time to open a new question up =/

Comment: @Jack: Yeah, this has shown to be a lot more information involved, information that originally wasn't in the question. :-)