# Using RayCasting for a 2D game

Tags: android, opengl-es, 2d, touch-event, raycasting

In one of my [earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799974/opengl-es-ontouchevents-problem-or-a-draw-problem-closed) I asked about onTouchEvents in OpenGL.  The idea was to create a simple app that drew a square where you pressed the screen. After a while I came out with an app that did everything the way it should have, but the square didn't redraw, it just vanished from the screen.

I have been told that to solve this I need to send a ray into the 3D environment of OpenGL from my 2D perspective, but for the life of me I can't understand why, because when I read up on raycasting it seemed to be used primarily for lighting effects. What exactly is raycasting?  Why would I need the z-axis at all when all I need to change in the squares position is the x and y axis from which coodinates can be found no matter what depth the touch registers at?

Comment: Your last question shows you're using a perspective projection instead of an orthographic projection - if you're doing 2D work, an orthographic projection matrix would be a lot simpler for you to use, so why are you using perspective?

Comment: just changing to orthogrphic now bit confused as to what the six floats on the glOthof() command are. Are they the parameters of the screen and the required depth of field?

Comment: Did you try [reading the documentation](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glOrtho.html)?  They define the clipping planes, which _could_ match your view width/height, but don't necessarily have to.  Also, depth of field is a completely different topic.

Comment: so in this case should the clipping planes be along the edges of the screen or surrounding the square?

Comment: For your purposes, probably the edges of the screen.

Comment: Would you reccomend using gluOrtho2D for a 2D game or does that restict things like zoom and use of camera objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a ray from the view to the screen to know where in the world to draw your square.  While this involves casting a ray, it's not ray casting as a rendering technique.  Unless you are working ortho, and even then to an extent, the math for converting from screen to world or world to screen needs to be done in order to find the correct point for your primitive.

Comment: And what commands does opengl have to implement a raycast for this use?

Comment: AFAIK none, but I am by no means an OpenGL expert, just someone who's run across code to do what you are trying to do in the past.  It involved a few matrix multiplications to convert the view frame, nothing more.